# Send Data from DataGridView to serial port

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, serial-port

I'm programming a windows form. One of its functions is to send the values input in a DatagridView through the serial port. Only it does not work. Here are a screenshot and the error code. I think it is the last empty row of the DG. Please let me know what you think is the problem.

[Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r8CKE.png)

[Windows Form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WxgJ8.png)

The outputbuffer variable in concatenated with the variables I want to send and then sent with serial port.  Is the last row the problem?

Should I add the word New before redifining.

COuld you suggest a code to send the data in DG to serial with Vb.net ?  I'm quite the beginner.

thank you!

Answer (score 0):

What is not working? What are you trying to talk with?

You could use [Com0Com](http://com0com.sourceforge.net/) to test your communication, but you should provide more info about your problem.

Do this 'thing' use control characters?
Did you look, if your SeriaPort configuration matches the serial configuration of the device you are talking with? Do this device expect a dataread before executing the next command?

You should describe your problem a little better and exactly.

The error says you are using an object that doesnt exist. You get the same error if you do like that:

```
Dim string as String
Dim stringLength = string.Length
```

You need an instance of the object you are using.

**If you delete .ToString() you should get desired result.**

And you should use ListView instead of DGV.